# Flexbox Layout Query, Rows to Columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to achieve a flexbox based transition **from this** (mobile):

[image: mobile layout]

**To this** (desktop):

[image: desktop layout]

However I am struggling to stack the two side panels vertically, my own code generates the main, search and other in a single row. I have not inserted webkit code for the sake of brevity.

**Code:**

```css
p {
  padding: 10px;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.header {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}

.search {
  flex: 1 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.main {
  flex: 1 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.other {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: Red;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .flex-container {} .search {
    flex: 1 0;
    order: 2
  }
  .main {
    flex: 3 0;
    order: 1;
  }
  .other {
    flex: 1 0;
    order: 3
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="header">
    <p>header</p>
  </div>
  <div class="search">
    <p>search</p>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <p>main</p>
  </div>
  <div class="other">
    <p>other</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/d2pmdvc4/

Comment: ttp://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words. Also provide the code you have so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you can't really do that with Flexbox if your main elements (`#main`, `#search` and `#other`) are siblings unless you know the fixed height value of `#search` (hacky solution with `position: absolute`):

```css
#header, .flex div {
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 1em; }

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative; }

#main { min-height: 300px; order: 2; }

#other { order: 3; }

/* desktop version */
@media (min-width:768px) {
  .flex { flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; }
  #main { width: 60%; }
  #search { order: 2; width: 40%; height: 100px }
  #other { width: 40%; position: absolute; top: 100px; right: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div id="header">header</div>
<div class="flex">
  <div id="main">main</div>
  <div id="search">search</div>
  <div id="other">other</div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/uhwzyr9b/

So logically you could try to wrap `#search` and `#other` inside another container but then you couldn't position `#content` between them because Flexbox can alter order of siblings only... The only workaround for that is probably JavaScript.

---

**Edit:** You can achieve your layout by using good old floats instead of Flexbox:

```css
#header, #main, #search, #other {
  padding:1em;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin-bottom:1em;
}

#main { min-height: 300px; }

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .container { overflow: auto; }
  #main { width: 60%; float: left; }
  #search { width:40%; float: right; }
  #other { width:40%; float: right; }
}
```

```html
<div id="header">header</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="search">search</div>
  <div id="main">main</div>
  <div id="other">other</div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/g5vxtbed/